# Adding multiple Image using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, spatial-index

I want to make NDBI indices to a certain location. But when I run the code it can only show part of it

```
//####################### Import SHP #######################
var countries = Indonesia //Import SHP DIVA GIS
var Nama_Kabupaten = ['Tarakan'] //Lihat di ArcMap
var daerah = countries.filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME_2', Nama_Kabupaten));//Definisikan Area of Interest
var area = ee.FeatureCollection(daerah);
Map.addLayer(daerah,{color:"Blue" },"Kabupaten", false);
Map.centerObject(area, 10);

var bands =['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'];//menentukan band
var collection= ee.ImageCollection ('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')//input data landsat
.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2019-12-31')
.filterBounds(daerah)
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.first()
Map.addLayer(collection.clip(daerah),{bands:['B4','B3','B2'], min:0, max:0.4},'Collection', false);

//NDBI
var ndbi = collection.normalizedDifference(['B6', 'B5']).rename('NDBI');
//Pembuatan Legenda
var ndbiVis = {
min: -1,
max: 1,
palette: [
'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163','fcca4a','fcd163', '1e11f5', '3024f6', 
'#4237f7', '#5349f7', '655cf8', '776ff9','8982fa'
],
}
//visualisasi citra
Map.addLayer(ndbi.clip(daerah), ndbiVis,"NDBI Rata-rata 2019");
```

[image: The blue shade is the area I want to get while the NDBI only shown in orange]

Answer (score 1):

When defining you variable collection, you are selecting only the first image of your collection when entering .first(). Your Area of Interest covers the Area of 2 Landsat images. Therefore, you need to make a Mosaic of multiple images to get full coverage.
To do that use a reducer. Remove the .first() and create a new variable:

```
var mean = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean())
```

Comment: I also recommend filtering out cloud pixels, reducing the date filter and filter for day time images for better results.